# MySQL: 1 large or individual tables?

Tags: mysql

I a trying to decide if I should create 1 table for each user or 1 table for all users.

1. I have a website where users can upload CSV files. I need to start all the records for each user. The CSV files will range from 5000 to 20,000 entries on average.
2. Each new import will first remove the previous user entries.
3. The user will not be editing the records. They will only be filtering to create reports.

No fully understanding the table structures of MySQL, I am not sure if storing all records within the one table makes sense, or if I should create individual tables per user.

Any insight would be appreciated, both Pros and Cons.

Thanks.

Comment: Individual table for each user is a very very bad idea.  Maybe you should read some database design books.

Comment: If there were more than one table, would their structure (number or type of columns) differ?

Comment: General rule: Data that varies dynamically should be in table contents, not table or column names. You can't join with table or column names, only column values.

Comment: Using varying table names means you have to write dynamic SQL throughout your application.

Comment: If you're creating tables that have a huge number of records and as such have performance problems, one solution is [partitioning](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/partitioning.html) or [sharding](https://www.mysql.com/products/cluster/scalability.html). It is almost never "create a whole bunch of tables, one for each *X*" because that massively complicates any schema changes you might want or need to make.

Comment: Thanks Eric. Very informative and a great idea if I wrote more than one SQL Statement every year. I must follow your responses.

Comment: Thank you, everyone. While I realize it was a very basic question, my concern was table corruption. If a table was unreadable for some reason, all users would be affected. That doesn't seem to be a concern.